# Guest Post Opportunities - To Post or Not to Post

Tags: seo, links

I have a modest blog with a PageRank of 2 which I have been writing myself for the past couple of years. Recently I received a request that someone wanted to write a guest post on my blog ... with a link to their site for a target keyword.

At this point I am inclined to say no and simply refuse to publish this post. But I recognize the work that has been put in writing this piece and wouldn't mind publishing the piece.

However the link provided is definitely a plug, will it harm my domain in any-way? Or do I put the no-follow tag (does that help?). Should I pass the juice or should I not?

Comment: please define what you mean with "link provided is definitely a plug"... if it helps, I would never pass juice to a site that I wouldn't feel comfortable giving my credit card number to.

Comment: with a plug i mean that it seems to be work of an agency on a link building scheme

Comment: ok, still. if you are not comfortable at buying something on that site or are uncomfortable in handing your cc number to that site, then nofollow the link. simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking yourself the wrong question. What you should as is:

> Does the article fit the topic of my site and help my readers?

It does not even matter if the article is a superb piece of literature if it is completely off-topic. If it does fit and you judge it appropriate content, then you can consider it as good karma for when you will be trying to get links to your site by guest blogging.

Do check the target link to make sure it points to a site related to the post. Definitely if someone is providing *useful* content for you for free, they expect it to be a follow link and it should be. If it is *not useful* content, it should not be posted.

Comment: good point ... it was a well worded article, but it does not really help my readers. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is now officially a bad idea. Google very much frowns upon this and allowing this kind of content and links on your website will cause you to fall prey to [Google's Penguin algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin). Basically, Penguin has rendered this form of promotion obsolete.